# How to run an application on headless remote Linux server and see the UI on my local Windows machine

Tags: java, html, linux, swing, jnlp

I have a swing application which takes some input files, manipulates them, and displays it in its UI. Currently I have a remote headless Linux machine where the data files are (changes everyday). So is there a way in which I can run that application on a remote Linux machine and see its UI on my local Windows machine? I heard it's possible using JNLP stuff. I am very new to this, any suggestion on this is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install on windows machine X server software and redirect the display of your software to your X server. Example X server software are Exceed, MobaXterm, etc. After you start the X server you should login in to the linux machine and execute

```
export DISPLAY=<your IP address>:0.0
```

and then run your software

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After setting the DISPLAY environment variable, when I tried running my application jar it giving below error.

No protocol specified
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '<My IP address>:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
 at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)

Comment: Do you have firewall on server or your machine?